# How to use a same DllEntry multiple times in custom action?

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3

I have a CustomAction written in C#. I want to call the DllEntry twice in my wix installer code. How can I achieve this?
I am doing this in the following manner. But this is working for me. Is there any other fair way to do this?

C# Code:

```
[CumtomAction]
public static ActionResult SymbolicLink(Session session)
{
     string s1=session.CustomActionData["value1"];
     string s2=session.CustomActionData["value2"];
       //mycode;
}
```

WixCode:

```
<CustomAction Id="ca" Property="dllCA" Value="value1='one';value2='two'" />
<CustomAction Id="dllCA" BinaryKey="InstallerLibrary" DllEntry="SymbolicLink" Execute="deferred"/>

<CustomAction Id="ca1" Property="dllCA1" Value="value1='three';value2='four'" />
<CustomAction Id="dllCA1" BinaryKey="InstallerLibrary" DllEntry="SymbolicLink" Execute="deferred"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
 <Custom Action="ca" Before="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
 <Custom Action="dllCA" After="ca"></Custom>

 <Custom Action="ca1" Before="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
 <Custom Action="dllCA1" After="ca1"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining it once should be suffice, ensuring you are setting the property correctly before you make the call to the `SymbolicLink` custom action:

```
<CustomAction Id="ca" Property="SymbolicLink" Value="value1='one';value2='two'" />
<CustomAction Id="ca1" Property="SymbolicLink" Value="value1='three';value2='four'" />
<CustomAction Id="dllCA" BinaryKey="InstallerLibrary" DllEntry="SymbolicLink" Execute="deferred"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="ca" Before="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="dllCA" After="ca"></Custom>

  <Custom Action="ca1" Before="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="dllCA" After="ca1"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake the property needs to be the name of your custom action. I will edit now.

Comment: In InstallExecuteSequene can i give link this?                        <Custom Action="ca" Before="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="dllCA" After="ca"></Custom>

  <Custom Action="ca1" After="ca"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="dllCA" After="ca1"></Custom>

Comment: Yes you should be, if it is still not working please create a verbose log, this should tell you what is happening. Or debug into your custom action..:)

Comment: Throws the exception `Error 4 Duplicate symbol 'WixAction:InstallExecuteSequence/dllCA' found. D:\*****\****\***.*** 1473 1 
`

Comment: Upon reflecting my code I have the same action called twice although one is in the `InstallUISequence` and the other `InstallExecuteSequence` Let me do some digging...:)